# SharePoint; Javascript repeating click event already on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, click

I have a SharePoint calendar, and I've got some Javascript code to force a calendar overlay event to open in a modal dialog. Basically, it forces them to open in a modal dialog via this code:

```
$('.ms-acal-ddiv a').click(function(){ 
     EditLink2(this,'WPQ2');
     return false; 
});
```

The problem is that there are already "native" events on the calendar which open with this code, and what is happening is that when you click on it, the events open TWICE with a modal dialog, thus rendering the page unusable.

I'm not savvy with writing jquery or javascript. How can I write the javascript to look for that code that's bolded, and prevent it from running if the link already executes with that?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `EditLink2(this,'WPQ2')` — what does it do? / where is it defined? Can you include it?

Comment: Yes, it is defined on the page. Here's how it works. You have a native calendar. All its event links open with "onclick
    EditLink2(this,'WPQ2');" When I overlay a calendar, its respective links do NOT open using that. They open in a new window; the href points to its direct URL instead of the "EditLink2(this,'WPQ2');". I am using the script I posted in the Fiddle to force them all to open using the "EditLink2(this,'WPQ2');", but by doing that, the native calendar's links are duplicating it, since it's already in the code.

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.ms-acal-ddiv a').click(function(event){
    EditLink2(this,'WPQ2');
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation()
    return false;
});
```

Which will prevent the `click` event from bubbling up.

- http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/
- http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

Comment: I will try your syntax to see if it works, but stopPropagation() was one of the FIRST things I tried. It didn't work, but then again, I may have had the syntax wrong.

Comment: Just tried it, and unfortunately, it doesn't work. The event still fires twice. Since there are actually two events opening in a modal dialog at the same time, the modal dialog background takes over the page and renders it useless.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? To a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co) if possible. It'll be easier to diagnose that way.

Comment: Sure. Here is the code. http://jsfiddle.net/dGSPj/

Even if I take out ALL the div's and leave only one in, the problem still occurs. Only one is enough to cause the links to double themselves. I think I only need to write a condition, for the jquery to "search" that if the event link already has the "EditLink2(this,'WPQ2');", to disregard it.

Comment: The fiddle you posted doesn't seem to work. The point of the fiddle is create a sandbox environment with all assets (necessary to re-create the error) included.

Comment: Oh, so sorry about that. Unfortunately, that's the best I can do, because it's a SharePoint environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The following code seems to have cleared it up for me:

```
$('.ms-acal-mdiv a, .ms-acal-ddiv a, .ms-acal-sdiv a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    EditLink2(this,'WPQ2');
});
```

I wonder if the `return false` gets in the way of whatever eventually tells the overlay to disappear.